# Connecting two planes in 3d

Tags: math, 3d

Given two planes positioned and rotated arbitrary to each other, I'm trying to determine which vertices should be connected. The image below (planes in black, connecting edges in red) illustrates two examples on how the planes might look:

[image: Connecting planes in 3d]

Comparing the distances between vertices won't work as the planes are not (necessarily) positioned directly above each other, and comparing the xyz components won't work either since they are not (necessarily) parallel and therefore might be twisted. I can't really think of any other solutions so I'm wondering if I need to go back and approach the problem in another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After ensuring that your rectangles are not intersecting and are not orthogonal, try minimizing the total distance between the paired points. There are only 24 ways to pair the vertices, so a clever solution is probably not needed. The other obvious way to approach this would be to ensure that the 4 new faces formed by connecting the vertices do not intersect, ie. you've formed a topologically simple solid.

Comment: Checking that the 4 new faces do not intersect seems like a good and simple way of doing it. Just need to figure out how to do the intersection test.. hmm.

Comment: Of course, it depends on *why* you want to do this, but minimizing the total distance (or total square distance or something) sounds like the way to go. I wouldn't spend too much time thinking about intersecting faces. If I understand the second picture correctly, none of the "faces" containing a red edge is in a single plane, so there is no flat surface that could reasonably be called a face; you'd either have to use some complicated surface, or break it into a couple of triangles (which there are two ways to do).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand how that would work though. Is the suggestion to run through all 24 ways to pair the vertices, and then take the solution where the total distance between each pair of vertices are lowest? A pseudo representation this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, I can see minimizing the total distance between the paired points work. I'm still not sure why I can be sure of this though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you want to do is to project the vertices of one plane onto the other one, and then match vertices of plane A with vertices of plane B according to a rule which works well for your problem. (Your drawings make it look as though the plane figures are not only translated and rotated relative to each other, but also scaled.)

Comment: You're right, they are also scaled. Sorry for not mentioning that.